# 1 layout for multiple fragments ?? is that possible?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

it is possible to do 1 layout for multiple fragments?

for example .. i have an layout let's called `A.XML` and i wanna use it on my fragments. there's 6 fragments which the layout of each fragment is SAME.. let say that only use `RecycleView` in layout of each fragment.

a.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".categoryFragment">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvFoodCtg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#f4f4f4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

is that possible if i want to use only `A.XML` for all my 6 fragments??? yeah you all know it save the memory.

Comment: just extend the fragment, which you want to use same layout, from the base fragment which inflate the layout that you want to use all fragments in its oncreateView.

Comment: before asking have you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use same `Layout` in as many as `Activities` and `Fragments` as you want